# Trash has reached maximum size?

Tags: kubuntu, trash, krusader

I'm on Kubuntu 11.04, and deleting in Krusader I get "Thrash has reached maximum size" even when I have 10M in `~/.local/share/Trash/files`. So my question is why is that? How do I set the allowed size of the trash bin?

Comment: Can you look at dolphin - settings -configure dolphin - wastebin.  Have you got the limit checkbox checked - and if so what is the percentage and the maximum value reported.  Does the max value equal the disk space actually left?

Comment: It's fine: I have 219G free, and in Dolphin it says 10% for a trash bin (it's 44,9G). I don't remember such a problem when I was using Dolphin. I'm later switched though to Krusader...

Comment: weird - sounds like a bug - if you dont get an answer - file a launchpad bug quoting the free-space comparison against dolphin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [UserAction](http://www.krusader.org/handbook/useractions.html) solves it:

```
mv %aList("Selected")% $HOME/.local/share/Trash/files
```

**Edit**:

The following works faster (but be careful)

```
rm -rf %aList("Selected")%
```

Answer (score 5):

Easier still...

- Open Dolphin
- Select 'Control' from the top of the window
- Select 'Configure Dolphin'
- Select Wastbin
- Un-check limit to maximum size
- Select apply

And you don't even have to open a horrid terminal

Answer (score 3):

Try Krusader `Tools > Empty trash` instead of empty trash button.

Removing trash metadata file works too - until you reach trash limit again - `rm ~/.local/share/Trash/metadata`

Comment: It was long time ago: the bug somehow got fixed with updates and upgrades.

Comment: In my case size of trash in the metadata file had somehow become a huge number, even though there were no files. Removing metadata worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it in the File manager (Dolphin in my case) configuration i went to Trash tab and there switched "Full trash" option from "Show a warning" to "Delete biggest files from trash". I am guessing other file managers have similar option.