# Krusader & Xfce - Wastebin is full

Tags: kde, xfce, trash, krusader

I've just installed Krusader and have annoying problem. Whenever I try to delete a file (move to trash) I've got a message:

> The wastebin has reached its maximum size!
>   Cleanup the wastebin manually.

My trash is totally empty so... I have no idea why it says that its full.
How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe it helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58866/trash-has-reached-maximum-size?rq=1

Comment: tried these answers but none worked. I found PCMan file manager useful for me ;)